# Using Eclipse to see where a function was called or class used

Tags: php, eclipse

I am using Eclipse with PHP and I am trying to trace back the calls functions and instantiations of classes to see why a certain piece of code was used.

The Eclipse interface is a bit cluttered.  How do I see the function call trace? Is that possible to do?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibily good solution would be to **use a debugger**, in step-by-step mode -- or by setting a breakpoint where you want to see the call-trace.

This will allow you to see variables and the call trace / history -- and, also, to go line by line into your source-code's execution.

About debugging and Eclipse, the following question + answers should be able to help : [**Good Free PHP debugger?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494288/138475)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS.  It seems the debuggers discussed in the discussion you point to only run on Windows.  Is that correct?

Comment: No : it runs on Linux/Ubuntu just fine *(I'm using Ubuntu on some machines)*

Comment: But the downloads URL http://www.xdebug.org/download.php only has Windows binaries.  How did you get it working on Ubuntu?  - Thanks!

Comment: There is a `php5-xdebug` package ; or you can use the pecl command : `pecl install xdebug` *(provided you have installed the required development tools)*

Comment: Dead link for "Good Free PHP debugger?"

Answer (score 0):

This post of me can't be actually a solution but just wanted to share.

In addition to what's already answered (which enables call trace during runtime), `PHP` plugin of `Eclipse` called [`PDT`](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) has a feature called `Call Hierarchy`. However, it looks like [this feature has not been implemented](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=27655#page_top) as of the latest version 3.1.

This is why I said my post isn't an answer, but I'm hoping that spreading the words like this would motivate the `PDT` `enter code here`plugin developers.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is the Parameter stack, found in Show view under PHP Tools and Parameter stack.